# Java streams: count distinct values in array of primitives

Tags: java, algorithm, math, java-8, java-stream

Why does a distinct count of an int array return a different result than a count of an Integer array? I would expect a result of 3 in both cases.

```
int[] numbers1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
System.out.println("numbers1: " + Arrays.toString(numbers1));
System.out.println("distinct numbers1 count: " + Stream.of(numbers1).distinct().count());

Integer[] numbers2 = { 1, 2, 3 };
System.out.println("numbers2: " + Arrays.toString(numbers2));
System.out.println("distinct numbers2 count: " + Stream.of(numbers2).distinct().count());
```

Results

```
numbers1: [1, 2, 3]
distinct numbers1 count: 1

numbers2: [1, 2, 3]
distinct numbers2 count: 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in the first one `Stream.of` method treats the whole array as one element - it creates a stream with an element of array. To work with array of primitives, you would have to use `Arrays.stream` instead.

Comment: I’d use `Arrays.stream` to stream over an existing array *in general*. Then, you don’t have think about it anymore. The factory methods in the `Stream` class are for the *varargs* use case, i.e. when you use `Stream.of(a)`, `Stream.of(a, b)`, or `Stream.of(a, b, c)`, etc., you also don’t need to think about the fact that there’s a specialized version for one of these calls…

Answer (score 6):

In your first case, the type of `Stream.of(numbers1)` is `Stream<int[]>` and it only has one value in it.

In your second case, the type of `Stream.of(numbers2)` is `Stream<Integer>` and it has 3 distinct values in it.

You an use `IntStream.of(1, 2, 3)` to get a stream of primitive `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Streams provides two static `Stream<T> of()` methods :

```
public static<T> Stream<T> of(T t) {..}
```

and

```
public static<T> Stream<T> of(T... values) {..}
```

The first method creates a stream consisting of a single object, which one provided as parameter, while the second method creates a stream consisting of the array elements.
In your case, the `int[]` parameter makes `of(T values)` to be invoked while `Integer[]` parameter makes `of(T... values)` to be invoked.
The result expected is so  `1`  and then `3`.

Why the compiler doesn't bind the two invocations to the same `of()` method ?

Because when the declared type of the argument passed is an array of objects, the compiler selects the most specific method available : `of(T... values)`.
But when the declared type of the argument passed is an array of primitive, that method doesn't match : `int` is not an `Object`. So the remaining method that the compiler can select is  `of(T t)`.

Long story short : to stream array of primitives, never use `Stream.of()` but use the specialized  class for : `IntStream.of()` or `DoubleStream.of()` that are designed for.

Comment: Or can also use `Arrays.stream`

Answer (score 2):

The first `Stream.of` returns a `Stream<int[]>`, and you have 1 distinct `int[]`, called `numbers1`. The second `Stream.of` returns a `Stream<Integer>`, and you have 3 distinct `Integers`, which are `1`, `2`, and `3`. You can fix this by replacing `Stream.of` with `Arrays.stream` for the first call to `Stream.of`, as `Arrays` has a specialized utility method taking an `int[]` and returning `IntStream`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Stream.of(numbers1)
```

with

```
Arrays.stream(numbers1)
```

to correctly convert the `int[]` to an `IntStream` ratther than `Stream<int[]>`.